# Cannot mount file as a volume in docker-compose after weekends, why?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

Today i got new error in my docker-environment. 
I just started my project (Web, Php and Postgres Containers), but Nginx container dont started, because the site.conf, which i mount with volumes is a "directory".

Last friday it was ok and worked nice for me. I dont change anything in this case. ;(

I created extra docker-compose file, where you can try to reproduce my error.

docker-compose File:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginxCr
    image: nginx:1.15.7
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
```

site.conf can be empty for testing.

after ***docker-compose up -d*** 
Container is not running.

***docker logs nginxCr*** provides following:

> 2019/03/04 14:49:25 [crit] 1#1: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf"
>   failed (21: Is a directory) nginx: [crit] pread()
>   "/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)

Somehow start the docker (docker compose) to creating directory instead of linking my config file.

I have Windows 10 Pro (Build 17134)

Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

UPDATE: 
Problem seems to be Windows only... on my Nix-Server it works fine

Comment: UPDATE 2: i got 3 "Definition" updates for Windows defender after Friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to `uncheck -> apply`

and then

`check -> apply` the Harddrive in "Shared Drivers" in Docker-Settings

***facepalm***

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `www` files in a sperate folder instead of `.`. Have a compose file like below:

```
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginxCr
    image: nginx:1.15.7
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
```

So, in your **Present working Dir** you should have a folder called `www` (so that you don't have to merge volumes) and a file called `site.conf`. Even if it is an empty file, you should have it in your directory. Otherwise, `docker` will create a folder in that name.

In case if you have a folder called `site.conf`, delete that folder and do `touch site.conf`, then do `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: nope, its not a solution ;(

2019/03/04 15:20:31 [crit] 1#1: pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)
nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf" failed (21: Is a directory)

Comment: i mean of course, i can create a docker file, which make touch, link and other things and it can/will be a solutiion, some how.. 

My first problem is - why its not working, 
Second - on friday it was working, today not, why?!

Comment: Whatever you provide in your dockerfile will reflect on the image which you create, but when you do a volume mount, you are creating a connection between your host and your container. So you need to have a file in your host ( if you are mounting a file). Otherwise, you can mount the entire folder

Comment: Can you post your current folder structure, then we can analyse why you are facing the issue

Comment: ProjectFolder/docker-compose.yml,

ProjectFolder/site.conf,

and the new one ProjectFolder/www

Comment: i created a public repo on github: [link](https://github.com/akdes/docker-volume-problem)

Comment: Submitted a PR with the required changes

Comment: Thanks, but again, this is not the problem... i tryed it... The problem is only on my windows maschine.